# Create loading/spinner overlay with Material2

Tags: material-design, angular-material2

I have this simple HTML

```
<body>
 <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

I would like to create a loading overlay, using Material:
https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview

Should I do something like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="foo" class="xyz">
    <app-root></app-root>
  </div>
</body>
```

and just toggle the class on the div with id="foo"? I can't figure out how to do an overlay the Material2 way, anybody know?

Comment: Why don't you use CDK overlay?

Comment: what is CDK in comparison to Material/Material2?

Answer (score 0):

This guy's post here:
https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2017/03/22/angular2-using-custom-loader-spinner-as-service-in-angular-2-application/

has all the answers.

I personally have one main event bus service. So put the `displayOverlay()` method in their. Otherwise followed his steps exactly and it worked fine.

Basically, you do this with router-outlet:

```
<router-outlet>
  <span *ngIf="showLoader" class="loading"></span>
</router-outlet>
```

then in the component which controls the above html, do this:

```
constructor(private mds: MainDataService, private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {

    const self = this;
    let to;

    this.mySub = this.mds.status.subscribe((val: boolean) => {
      self.showLoader = val;
      clearTimeout(to);
      to = setTimeout(function () {
        self.ref.detectChanges();
      }, 100);
    });

  }
```

so in your main data bus service, just call:

```
  displayOverlay(value: boolean) {
    this.status.next(value);
  }
```

Admittedly "status" is not the right property name, but I will leave it to be the same name as the examples form the article.